# How do not show module in specific hook?

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

In product.tpl I have two hooks for example:

Hook showing product price:

```
{hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type="price"}
```

and Hook showing accesories price:

```
{hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$accessory type="price"}
```

When I hooked some module to hook `displayProductPriceBlock` it is display twice on page, once in product price and second in all display accesories. Normally I can filter this where display module using `type` params like this:

```
if ((isset($params['type']) && $params['type'] == 'price')
```

but those hooks have thesame `type`, so how I can do this using `product=$accessory` and `product=$product`.

I already try doing this in module controller adding to  hook `displayProductPriceBlock` that:

```
if ((isset($params['type']) && $params['type'] == 'price') && (isset($params['product']) && $params['product'] != 'accessory'))
```

but this is not working for me. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand what do you want to do :(

Comment: Yes my english is bad... Basicly I have some module and it is display in hook but in product.tpl these hook is twice so module is display twice in product.tpl I want show it only once. This hooks have differences in one is: `product=$accessory` and in second `product=$product`. How can I use this differences in module controller to not display this module twice?

Comment: Please write in the question exactly the code that you're using... With your explanation I suggest to you to use a variable like a semaphore or a flag, in the first call you set this var to true (already called) so the next time check if the var is true you don't do your stuff

Comment: I edit question just now, it should be more clear.